# Set the Layout in the TableView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Made one TableView in Which i want to Set the Each and Every Contain in the middle of the every row and there are multiple textview in the one row then how to set it. . . ?
The code is As below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Name" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text="Address" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text="E-Mail" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text="Phone No." android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="3dip" android:background="#FF909100" />
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Shreyash" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView android:text="Godhra" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text="sbm_mahajan" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView android:text="9825056129" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#FF909060" />
</TableLayout>
```

see the Below Image:

[image]

Comment: Ok I forgot to put the Code. .  Now See the updated Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableRow android:padding="15dip">
        <TextView android:text="Name" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="Address" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="E-Mail" android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="Phone No." android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="3dip" android:background="#FF909100" />
    <TableRow android:padding="15dip">
        <TextView android:text="Shreyash" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="Godhra" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="sbm_mahajan" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="9825056129" android:textColor="#FF778899"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <View android:layout_height="2dip" android:background="#FF909060" />
</TableLayout>`
```

Check this now.

Comment: Ok Thanks for Reply. . .  Let me Check it. . .

Comment: Thanks. ..  It Works. .  Let me Set it For My Application. . .

Comment: Realy Thanks Swathi. . .  Its Works Great. . .

Comment: yes its Works. . .  but now i want to Set the Image instead of the TextView. It not shows same image for all the same images. . .  i have post the code for the Image,.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following code:-

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
     android:gravity="center">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Open..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-O"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Save..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-S"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Save As..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-Shift-S"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="X"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Import..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="X"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Export..."
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Ctrl-E"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: HUmmm, its already available on the developer site. . .  Please again refer my code. i have multiple data in Single row Each data i want to set in the middle of the Column. got it ?

Comment: I hav Checked it. . . But u didnt get it. . .

Comment: I mean to have a Each and Every Text View in the Middle of the Center In Every Column. .

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:id="@+id/rl_complete_string_end"
                                android:paddingTop="14dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dip">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@+id/tl_question"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:shrinkColumns="1">

<TableRow>

<TextView android:text="Name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView android:text="Address"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView android:text="E-Mail"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView android:text="Phone No."
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show My new code to set Images:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

> 

```
<TableRow 
    android:padding="15dip"> 

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/icon" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 

</TableRow> 

<View 
    android:layout_height="3dip" 
    android:background="#FF909100" /> 

<TableRow 
    android:padding="15dip"> 

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:textColor="#FF778899" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <TextView 
        android:text="Godhra" 
        android:textColor="#FF778899" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <TextView 
        android:text="sbm_mahajan" 
        android:textColor="#FF778899" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip"/> 

    <TextView 
        android:text="9825056129" 
        android:textColor="#FF778899" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" /> 
</TableRow> 

<View 
    android:layout_height="2dip" 
    android:background="#FF909060" />
```